# Easy way to move formulas

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

Anybody know of a quick and easy way to move formulas from one worksheet to another worksheet while maintaining their location and worksheet information. I have a budgeting sheet that searchs down a column for the last bit of data entered however the formulas in that column are interfering with the script. The script im using is this:

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()

'Updateby20150305

    Dim xLastRow As String

    With Application.ActiveSheet

         xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    MsgBox xLastRow

End Sub
```

I can even move them to a new location in the same worksheet but they just need to maintain their cell locations. Is there any easy way to move them all at once?

Comment: Are you sure that `how do I move the formulas` is the 'right' question? It looks like you have just problems selecting the correct range for something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you copy a formula from one cell to another, Excel tries to "help" you by adjusting the cell references.  For example, say we have in cell **E1** of *Sheet1* the formula:

```
=A1+A2
```

and we copy this to *Sheet2* cell **E2** we get:

```
=A2+A3
```

So the pasted formula has adjusted cells and refers to cells on the new sheet!

We can get around the second problem by using:

```
=Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!A2
```

in *Sheet1*.  Rather than copying the formula from one cell to another we can use:

```
Sub ExactCopyFormula()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Formula = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Formula
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the code for looping over the specified range:

```
Sub Copy2()
    Dim r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D9000")
        addy = r.Address(0, 0)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(addy).Formula = r.Formula
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah I see so .Range("A1:D9000) would copy all formulas in that range from sheet1 to sheet 2 and id be able to then delete the formulas in sheet 1 without any loss.

Comment: @Gehn47  ***NO***  ....you will need a loop.............I will edit my answer in a little while.

Comment: @Gehn47  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you for that. Appreciate greatly the help.